# Why DSolve and NDSolve give different answer

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

Consider these code, which solve the same equation using `DSolve` and `NDSolve`, why do they give different answer? Which one is correct? I'm using version 9.01 on Mac.

```
sol1 = DSolve[
   Thread[D[{y1[t], y2[t]}, 
       t] == {{0, E^(2 I t)}, {-E^(I t), 0}}.{y1[t], y2[t]}]~
    Join~{y1[0] == 0, y2[0] == 1}, {y1, y2}, t];
sol2 = NDSolve[
   Thread[D[{y1[t], y2[t]}, 
       t] == {{0, E^(2 I t)}, {-E^(I t), 0}}.{y1[t], y2[t]}]~
    Join~{y1[0] == 0, y2[0] == 1}, {y1, y2}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}];

Plot[{Re@(y1[t] /. sol1), Re@(y1[t] /. sol2)}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

[image]

Comment: It helps if you split real and imaginary parts : `sol3 = DSolve[
   Thread[D[{y1[t], y2[t]}, t] == 
      ComplexExpand[{{0, E^(2 I t)}, {-E^(I t), 0}}.{y1[t], y2[t]}, 
       TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]]~
    Join~{y1[0] == 0, y2[0] == 1}, {y1, y2}, t];`.

Comment: Good question, Why?....?